# Scrapy: My code is only parsing from 1 URL

Tags: python, web-crawler, scrapy

I am trying to parse all urls containing "133199" within my site.
Unfortunately, my code only parses 1 url within the whole site.  There should be well over 20k urls.

The following code correctly crawls the whole website and is somehow parsing the first URL containing 133199, but not the rests.

```
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor

from wallspider.items import Website


class mydomainSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "activewear"
    allowed_domains = ["www.mydomain.com"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.mydomain.com/",]

    rules = (
    Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=(),deny=('/[1-9]$', '(bti=)[1-9]+(?:\.[1-9]*)?', '(sort_by=)[a-zA-Z]', '(sort_by=)[1-9]+(?:\.[1-9]*)?', '(ic=32_)[1-9]+(?:\.[1-9]*)?', '(ic=60_)[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]*)?', '(search_sort=)[1-9]+(?:\.[1-9]*)?', 'browse-ng.do\?', '/page/', '/ip/', 'out\+value', 'fn=', 'customer_rating', 'special_offers', 'search_sort=&', ))),
    Rule (SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=('133199', ),)
    , callback="parse_items", follow= True),
    )

    def parse_items(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        sites = hxs.select('//html')
        items = []

        for site in sites:
            item = Website()
            item['referer'] = response.request.headers.get('Referer')
            item['url'] = response.url
            item['title'] = site.xpath('/html/head/title/text()').extract()
            item['description'] = site.select('//meta[@name="Description"]/@content').extract()
            item['canonical'] = site.xpath('//head/link[@rel="canonical"]/@href').extract()
            item['response'] = response.status
            items.append(item)

        return items
```

This is my console log of the only URL that gets parsed.  The website is a couple million pages so I cannot display the whole log.

```
Scraped from <200 http://www.mydomain.com/browse/apparel/5438?_refineresult=true&facet=special_offers%3AClearance&ic=32_0&path=0%3A5438&povid=cat133199-env200983-moduleC052312-lLinkSubnav1Clearance>
    {'canonical': [u'http://www.mydomain.com/browse/apparel/5438/'],
     'description': [u"Shop for Apparel - mydomain.com. Buy products such as Disney Girls' Minnie Mouse 2 Piece Pajama Coat Set at mydomain and save."],
     'referer': 'http://www.mydomain.com/cp/133199',
     'response': 200,
     'title': [u'\nApparel - mydomain.com\n'],
     'url': 'http://www.mydomain.com/browse/apparel/5438?_refineresult=true&facet=special_offers%3AClearance&ic=32_0&path=0%3A5438&povid=cat133199-env200983-moduleC052312-lLinkSubnav1Clearance'}
2013-12-20 09:45:54-0800 [activewear] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.mydomain.com/cp/Cats/202073?povid=P1171-C1110.2784+1455.2776+1115.2956-L440> (referer: http://www.mydomain.com/)
2013-12-20 09:45:54-0800 [activewear] DEBUG: Redirecting (301) to <GET http://www.mydomain.com/browse/pets/birds/5440_228734/?amp;ic=48_0&amp;ref=243033.244996&catNavId=5440&povid=P1171-C1110.2784+1455.2776+1115.2956-L439> from <GET http://www.mydomain.com/browse/Birds/_/N-591gZaq90Zaqce/Ne-57ix?amp%3Bic=48_0&amp%3Bref=243033.244996&amp%3Btab_All=&catNavId=5440&povid=P1171-C1110.2784+1455.2776+1115.2956-L439>
2013-12-20 09:45:54-0800 [activewear] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.mydomain.com/browse/team-sports/soccer/4125_4161_432196?povid=P1171-C1110.2784+1455.2776+1115.2956-L277> (referer: http://www.mydomain.com/)
2013-12-20 09:45:55-0800 [activewear] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.mydomain.com/browse/sports-outdoors/golf/4125_4152?povid=P1171-C1110.2784+1455.2776+1115.2956-L276> (referer: http://www.mydomain.com/)
2013-12-20 09:45:55-0800 [activewear] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.mydomain.com/browse/team-sports/football/4125_4161_434036?povid=P1171-C1110.2784+1455.2776+1115.2956-L275> (referer: http://www.mydomain.com/)
2013-12-20 09:45:55-0800 [activewear] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.mydomain.com/cp/1164750?povid=P1171-C1110.2784+1455.2776+1115.2956-L362> (referer: http://www.mydomain.com/)
2013-12-20 09:45:55-0800 [activewear] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.mydomain.com/browse/gifts-registry/specialty-gift-cards/1094765_96894_972339?povid=P1171-C1110.2784+1455.2776+1115.2956-L361> (referer: http://www.mydomain.com/)
2013-12-20 09:45:55-0800 [activewear] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.mydomain.com/cp/pet-supplies/5440?povid=P1171-C1110.2784+1455.2776+1115.2956-L438> (referer: http://www.mydomain.com/)
```

Comment: Could you share your console log? Also, the order of rules is important. [See the documentation here.](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.contrib.spiders.CrawlSpider.rules) _"If multiple rules match the same link, the first one will be used, according to the order they’re defined in this attribute."_ So you could try changing the order of your 2 rules if that changes anything

Comment: @pault.I've spent some time switching the rules around.  When I swtich the rules to: **`rules = (
    Rule (SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=('133199', ),)
    , callback="parse_items", follow= True),
    Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=(),deny=('/[1-9]$', '(bti=)[1-9]+(?:\.[1-9]*)?', '(sort_by=)[a-zA-Z]', '(sort_by=)[1-9]+(?:\.[1-9]*)?', '(ic=32_)[1-9]+(?:\.[1-9]*)?', '(ic=60_)[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]*)?', '(search_sort=)[1-9]+(?:\.[1-9]*)?', 'browse-ng.do\?', '/page/', '/ip/', 'out\+value', 'fn=', 'customer_rating', 'special_offers', 'search_sort=&', ))),
    )`** it doesn't parse anything.